# How to get Wordpress pages featured image from guttenberg block editor?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-rest-api, wordpress-gutenberg

I want to get a list of pages including their featured image from the js editor of a custom guttenberg block. 
The problem is, that by default the featured image is not included in the REST API response. It can be enabled by appending `?_embed=true` to the REST request. (https://fancysquares.blog/posts/how-to-get-the-featured-image-url-in-wp-api-v2/).

My question is how to do this using the withSelect API. I could not find a way to add the `?_embed=true` to the request.

Here is my code for getting the pages:

```
edit: withSelect(select => {
    return {
        posts: select('core').getEntityRecords('postType', 'page', {
            per_page: 3,
            parent: wp.data.select("core/editor").getCurrentPostId(),
        })
    };
})(({ posts, className, attributes, setAttributes }) => {
   //rendering
}),
```

Comment: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/317331/33790

Answer (score 4):

I think this should solve your problem:

```
edit: withSelect(select => {
    return {
        posts: select('core').getEntityRecords('postType', 'page', {
            per_page: 3,
            _embed: true, //HERE
            parent: wp.data.select("core/editor").getCurrentPostId(),
        })
    };
})(({ posts, className, attributes, setAttributes }) => {
   //rendering
}),
```

I'm sorry for the late response, but maybe someone else can use it.

Comment: `_embed` is the hero ! is was actually manually querieing terms, images etc... i could have done this the easy way to start with <3